# React.JS npm start error after successful installation of all packages using create-react-app

Tags: reactjs

I have followed bellow steps for reactjs environment setup.

1. Installed Node.js with version - v10.16.3
2. npm version - 6.14.5
3. npm install -g create-react-app
4. create-react-app my-app
5. cd my-app
6. npm start.

But when I start it using npm start. It is giving me error like `events.js:174 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event`

Below is the error stack trace:

```
Starting the development server...

events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:246:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! react-app@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the react-app@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Prashant Kamble\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-06-26T13_39_25_395Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to navigate to your project folder and type this commands. It helps me.

rm -rf node_modules

rm package-lock.json

rm  yarn.lock

npm cache clear --force

npm install

Comment: Thanks I will follow these steps.

Answer (score 0):

**It was giving issue for react-script version >= 3.0.0**

I am able to find solution for this with my one of colleague Shivani i.e we downgraded the version of react-script from 3.4.0 to 2.1.8 by using below command nothing else changed.

Command needs to be executed from project folder or our app so that it can update package.json

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scripts/v/2.1.8

```
npm i react-scripts@2.1.8
```